# Get the SAML assertion when Salesforce is Identity provider

Tags: saml

I am using one salesforce org as a Identity provider and another org as a service provider. Using connected app when I try to login from Identity provider to service provider Salesforce org, It logins me to service provider org without any credentials.

How can I obtain SAML assertion from Identity provider org for some testing?

Answer (score 2):

Found it myself. One can get the SAML assertion from service provider salesforce org.
Go to Set-up -> Single Sign on Settings -> SAML Assertion validator. This will display the latest failed assertion. Please note SAML assertion will be displayed here only in case of failure. In case of success, Salesforce do not stores anything.